# Angular CSS HTML inline label and input field. how to float label to the left and input field to the right

Tags: html, css, angular

I am working on an angular form where I have many label input field combination. I got the label and input file styled with inline block so they are rendering on the same row. I want to float or pull the label to the far left while the input field control is float or pull to the far right. I tried a few CSS changes but no success so far, any help is appreciated.

```css
.input-w label, .input-w select {
    float:none; 
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;

}

.label {
    padding: 0.21em 0.4em 0.2em;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
       <div class="row">
         <div class="col">
      
           <div class="input-w label">
             <label for="dropdown1" class="form-inline">Options: </label>
             <select formControlName="dropdown1" class="form-control form-line">
               <option *ngFor="let option of Options" 
                              [ngValue]="option.value">
                              {{option.display}}
               </option>
             </select>
               
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Instead of floating, could you use flexbox?  If so, you could use `justify-content: space-between` on the `.input-w.label` element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets change the css property like below so that you can get the desired output :

**Solution 1**

```
.input-w label, .input-w select {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.input-w select{
   float: right;
}

.label {
    padding: 0.21em 0.4em 0.2em;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

adding **float right** will help you moving the label to far right.

**Solution 2 :**

Remove all css added to **label** & **select** tags and add this css to class **input-w** . Simple and effective

```
.input-w {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just need to rearrange your css classes a bit. Move the .label class off the container div and put it on the label, there no need for the container too have the float. Also can add a seperate class to put float right on select. I have included a sample jsfiddle.

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
       <div class="row">
         <div class="col">
      
           <div class="input-w">
             <label for="dropdown1" class="form-inline label">Options: </label>
             <select formControlName="dropdown1" class="form-control form-line select-input">
               <option *ngFor="let option of Options" 
                              [ngValue]="option.value">
                              {{option.display}}
               </option>
             </select>
               
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

```
.input-w label, .input-w select {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: block;
}

.label {
    padding: 0.21em 0.4em 0.2em;
    box-shadow: none;
    float: left;
}

.select-input{
  float: right;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e0wzpsb3/